# I need help understanding this Math

Tags: javascript, math

I have function which is designed to multiply all of the values listed in the arrays below.
The function works, but I do not understand how the math is being done, as far as the J iteration is concerned.
On the first trip through the for loop, the J is equal to 0.
The values would then be [1,2][0], which should equal 0 (1*2*0=0).
But the answer is 1...
I don't understand how this equation is playing out. 
This is how my console is logging the information:

```
 array: 1,2 J: 0  answer: 1;
 array: 1,2 J: 1  answer: 2;
 array: 3,4 J: 0  answer: 6;
 array: 3,4 J: 1  answer: 24;
 array: 5,6,7 J: 0  answer: 120;
 array: 5,6,7 J: 1  answer: 720;
 array: 5,6,7 J: 2  answer: 5040;
```

JS code:

```
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  var product = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      product = product * arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  return product;
}


multiplyAll( [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7] ] );
```

Comment: `arr[i][j]` is never zero. When `j` is `0`, `arr[i][j]` is `1`.

Comment: maybe you could consider using js array functions for nice readable code. Following does the same as your code:
multiply = (a, b) => a * b
array.flat().reduce(multiply)

Answer (score 2):

You're never multiplying by zero. 'i' iterates over each element of the array (first [1, 2], then [3, 4], then [5, 6, 7]), and then 'j' iterates over the each element of all those arrays inside the main array. So for example, in the first iteration, arr[i][j] represents '1'.

Answer (score 2):

The first loop is going to each array. That means: `arr[i] = [1,2] , [3,4], [5,6,7]`.
The second loop is going to each element of the current array. `arr[i][j] = 1, 2, 3, 4...`

In the end all values get multiplied.

Answer (score 2):

> The values would then be [1,2][0], ~~which should equal 0 (1*2*0=0)~~.

it's wrong. the real operation is (1 * 2) only

```js
let doubleArray = [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7] ]
let i = 0
let j = 0
console.log( doubleArray[i][j] ) // --> 1
```

i and j are only indexes on your tables, they are not used in any math calculation

your code is equivalent to ( with no use of indexes i and j )

```js
function multiplyAll(doubleArray)
  {
  let product = 1
    ;
  for (let inArray of doubleArray)
    {
    for (let num of inArray)
      {
      product *= num
      }
    }
  return product
  }
let result  = multiplyAll( [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7] ] )
  ;
console.log( result )  //  5040
```